# Extracting a part of table name and printing it on console

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sqlplus

How to extract a part of table name in Oracle 11g and print it on console?

For example we have a tables in the following manner:

Table name: College_football_players with attributes as Name and age.
Table name: College_VolleyBall_players with attributes as Name and age.

Now I need to print age and name of all the players playing both the games with repetition(if any).

The code I used is:

select * from college_football_players union all college_VolleyBall_players;

In addition to this I need to add the game played by the player which should be extracted from the name of the table. Is there any possible way to do this without adding another column to the tables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.*, 'football' as game from college_football_players f 
union all 
select v.*, 'volleyBall' from college_VolleyBall_players v;
```

Comment: Could you please explain me the syntax and what f.* means? I am new to this subject and learning it.

Comment: @Divya Teja '*' is a all-columns-wildcard. It lets you select all the columns from your table. 'f' is a table alias. For example, if your table has 2 columns: id and player_name then you can use 'select f.id, f.player_name from college_football_players f'

Comment: @Divya Teja 'select f.* from college_football_players f' is the same

Comment: @Divya Teja The query 'select *, 'football' as game from college_football_players' won't run because it's incorrect syntax in Oracle. That's why I used alias 'f'

Comment: Ok, I know the syntax for using select query and the use of '*'. I got confused with the usage of "f.*". Thanks for the explanation.